# For $p \in \mathbb{K}_{k}[X]$, the function $n \mapsto p(x_{0}+h n)$ is an arithmetic sequence of order $k$

Tags: polynomials, summation, interpolation

I'm reading *Remark 12.14.c* from textbook *Analysis I* by Amann/Escher.

$\mathbb{K}_{k}[X]$ is the ring of polynomials whose degrees are less than or equal to $k$.

> [image]

Here is Formula 12.15:

> [image]

where the *divided difference operator* $\triangle_{h}$ of length $h$ is defined by

> [image]

Here is Remark 8.19 (c):

> [image]

---

I follow authors' hint but still no close to the proof that the function $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}, \quad n \mapsto p\left(x_{0}+h n\right)$ is an arithmetic sequence of order $k$.

**My attempt:**

> **Lemma:** Let $E$ be a vector space over field $\mathbb{K}$. On $E^{\mathrm{N}}$ define the difference operator $\triangle$ by $\triangle f_{n} :=f_{n+1}-f_{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f \in E^{\mathbb{N}}$. Then we have $$\triangle^{k} f_{n} = \sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j} {k \choose j} f_{n+j}, \quad k, n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad f \in E^{\mathbb{N}}$$

By 12.15 and Remark 8.19 (c), $$p =\sum_{i=0}^{k} \frac{\triangle_{h}^{i} p\left(x_{0}\right)}{i !} \prod_{j=0}^{i-1}\left(X-x_{j}\right)$$ and thus $$p(x_{n+i}) =\sum_{i=0}^{k} {n+i \choose i} \triangle^i p(x_0)$$

By lemma, $$\triangle^{k} f_{n} = \sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-i} {k \choose i} p(x_{n+i})$$

From here, I'm stuck at proving $\triangle^{k} f_{n}$ is a constant.

Could you please get me some hints to finish the proof?

Comment: It is constant because $p$ is a polynomial of degree $\le k$ and $\Delta^k x^m$ is a polynomial of degree $m-k$. Conversely if $\Delta^k f_n$ is constant then there is a polynomial of degree $\le k$ with $ p(n) = f_n$ for $n \le k$ which implies $p(n) = f_n$ for all $n$

Comment: Hi @reuns, I have just figured out a proof of your statement and posted it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301157/assume-f-in-mathbbk-mathbbn-and-there-exists-p-in-mathbbk-kx-su). Could you please verify my attempt? Thank you so much!